# Google Drive stripped Outlook 2010 of all emails, contacts, etc

Tags: windows-7, google-drive

I have a business that requires I use the business email:  david@mydomain.com

I loaded Google Drive as a free cloud to share project details with co-worker.

Side effect is that Outlook 2010 does not work now.  All incoming emails are now transferred to my personal Google account.

Now I can not send business emails inclusive of business headers and footers since Outlook is erroring on send/receive.  And all my history of email organization on Outlook is gone.

I was previously successfully syncing outlook through Google calendar to keep my blackberry sync'd